# Switching tabs from IE BHO C++

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

I have an IE browser opened with several tabs, I need to switch the active tab from my bho, that is attached to IE. Is anyone how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public interface for doing this; you can use an undocumented object as shown in this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5079/Mouse-Gestures-for-Internet-Explorer or you could synthesize a keystroke (e.g. CTRL+TAB or CTRL+SHIFT+TAB) to cause IE to switch tabs on your behalf.